# Parse JSON without specific element name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to parse the JSON response of Country & State from below mentioned URL.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mayurah/5f4a6b18b1aa8c26910f/raw/countriesToCities.json

```
{
"China":  [
"Guangzhou",
"Fuzhou",
"Beijing",
"Baotou",
"Hohhot",
"Guiyang",
"Yinchuan",
"Nanjing",
"Changzhou",
"Chuzhou",
"Hefei",
"Jinan",
"Qingdao",
"Harbin",
"Zhaodong",
"Taiyuan",
"Xi'an",
.
.
.
 }
 ]
```

I want the result as,

- Guangzhou, China
- Taiyuan, China

I am using AngularJS, Following is a piece of code of my controllers.js file.

```
var
apiUrl = {
    countryStateList: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mayurah/5f4a6b18b1aa8c26910f/raw/countriesToCities.json'
};

countryData.controller('countryDataCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get(apiUrl.countryStateList).success(function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    $scope.countryStateList = data;
});
}]);
```

And, in my HTML file, code is something like this,

```
<ul ng-repeat="country in countryStateList">
<li>{{ STATE_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME }}</li>
</ul>
```

- STATE_NAME & COUNTRY_NAME are just for in display information. Both must be replaced with Angular code.

The problem is JSON element names are itself country names. Can someone tell me how to parse the same in AngularJS/Javascript.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON parsing. Can you show us the code you currently have so that we can show you how to modify it? Also, what are you planning to do with the values if you have them in a format like that. If you put the whole thing in a dropdown box, it will be a huge burden on your user and their browser.

Comment: @JLRishe Please check the edited part with code sample.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Do you want a separate `ul` for each country? Or do you want all of the `STATE_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME` pairs listed in one big `ul` for everything?

Comment: Could you please answer the question I asked yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by parsing the whole JSON:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(RAW_JSON_STING);
var newJsonObject = [];

// Loop through it
for (var interator in jsonObject)
{
    for (var it = 0; it < iterator.length; it++)
    {
        newJsonObject.push(iterator[it] + ", " + iterator);
    }
}
```

No guarantee the code above will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-repeat will not be useful in your case. This would be possible using directive.

```
<datalist id="stateCountry">
    <custom-datalist-option data-array="countryStateList"></custom-datalist-option>
</datalist>
```

Link a directive function and create an option using using it.

Here is the [**Update Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pankaj_287/bd1fa7ou/7/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above code is really fast compared to what I was implementing in JavaScript. But, can you tell me how I can do this with datalist. I am trying this code, `<datalist id="stateCountry" ng-repeat="(country, value) in countryStateList">
        <option ng-repeat="state in value | filter:selectCity" value="{{ state + ', ' + country }}">
    </datalist>` But, I am not getting the desired result. In browser source I can see datalist is getting repeated.

Comment: sorry for late response. I've updated the fiddle as per your comment, now i'm creating option using simple directive. Hope that would be helpful to you. Thanks :)